# Proof of equivalence between two definitions of the limit superior

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

In Bartle's *Introduction to Real Analysis*, he defines the **limit superior** $x^*$ of a bounded sequence of reals $(x_n)$  as the infimum of the set $V$ of $v \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $v < x_n$ for at most a finite number of $n \in \mathbb{N}$. He then shows that if $x^* = \limsup x_n$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then there are at most a finite number of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^* + \epsilon < x_n$ and an infinite number of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^* - \epsilon < x_n$.

I had a question regarding the proof of the fact in the last sentence. Given $\epsilon > 0$, since $x^* = \inf V$ we have that $\exists v \in V$ such that $x^* \leq v < x^* + \epsilon$. Bartle then claims that this implies $x^* \in V$, though I am not sure why. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/rCiPCzZ.png) is the proof taken directly.

Comment: I think that's a typo; you don't actually use that $x^*$ lies in $V$ in that argument: you use that $x^*+\epsilon$ lies in $V$ (which is true because if $v\in V$ and $v\lt y$, then $y\in V$). So that should be "$x^*+\epsilon$", not $x^*$.

Comment: Yes, the proof works now. Thank you. I am forever indebted.